# What are all the random seeds for TensorFlow V2.x and tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I only use tf.keras in TensorFlow V2.x. What are all the seeds that I can set? I have only found tf.random.set_seed(). Are there other seeds?

Comment: I have also set the np.random.seed and os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']. I use CPU for the computation. But the results still vary from run to run.

Comment: Can you please explain more about your requirement. Here in this link you have different possibilities explained https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

Comment: I am trying to develop a model that can produce repeatable results. I only use tf.keras. The set_seed() still yields variable results. Anything else I can set so that my models can produce repeatable results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the experiments that we have tried. The results for `tf.random.set_seed` are identical.

**Experiment 1  :** `tf.random.set_seed(1234)` set only once.

```
import tensorflow as tf

for i in range(5):
  print("Iteration Number :", i)
  tf.random.set_seed(1234)
  print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
  print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A2'
  print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A3'
```

**Output -** Generates same value for every iteration for `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.

```
Iteration Number : 0
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 1
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 2
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 3
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 4
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Lets restart the runtime or kernel and verify the result.

**Output -** Generates same value for every iteration for `A1`, `A2` and `A3`. And also the results match with the previous run results.

```
Iteration Number : 0
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 1
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 2
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 3
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 4
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.59750986], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

**Experiment 2 :** `tf.random.set_seed(1234)` set for every operation.

```
for i in range(5):
  print("Iteration Number :", i)
  tf.random.set_seed(1234)
  print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
  tf.random.set_seed(1234)
  print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
  tf.random.set_seed(1234)
  print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
```

**Output -** All the values are identical as `tf.random.set_seed` is set for every operation.

```
Iteration Number : 0
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 1
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 2
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 3
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Iteration Number : 4
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

The values remain the same even after you restart the kernel.

If you still have any doubts, kindly share the reproducible code with your expectations.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: Thanks, but what you described is for tf.Tensor. I can get reproducible values for tf.Tensor too. But my question is about tf.keras. Can you give an example that you can get reproducible results with tf.keras? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the reproducible code so that we can understand better. I am not not getting for which operation you are looking within tf.keras. tf.keras is a framework from which we can import libraries.

Comment: Problem solved. It yields reproducible results now. Thanks and I appreciate your help.